# Using a variable (changes based on the value of another cell) as a cell reference in the Sum function

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to create a sum function where the range changes based on the value of another cell.

I tried this: =sum(A10:address(12,1)) and it returns an error stating that I need a valid range in the Sum function.

What is the proper syntax to make this work? Or is there another better way to do this?

Comment: It would help if you could share a sample sheet with *realistic*-demo data and expected output(**manually entered**) so as for us to get a clear picture & workout a solution. You may also use the [**anonymous blank sheet maker**](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) provided by [*docs community forum*](https://support.google.com/) incase you do not wish to share a sheet from your google account.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`INDIRECT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?hl=en) function. Assuming A1 contains the end of the range, like `A20` for example, the formula would be:

```cpp
=SUM(INDIRECT("A10:"&A1))
```